# Как передать данные структуры из одной функции в другую. Язык Си

Tags: c, функции, структуры

Пишу консольную программу (Записная книжка). Дошел до момента когда нужно внести изменения в таблицу. Не знаю как передать данные структуры из одной функции в другую, при том как одна из них является вложенной. Подскажите как правильно это сделать?

Вот первая функция:

```
void UPDATE_RECORD(FILE* fPtr)
{
    struct DATA notebook;
    int numper=0;
    VIEW_DATA(fPtr);
    printf("Введите номер человека, данные которого нужно изменить\n-> ");
    scanf("%d", &numper);

    notebook.number = numper;
    ENTER_DATA();

    fseek(fPtr, notebook.number * sizeof(struct DATA), SEEK_SET);
    fwrite(&notebook, sizeof(struct DATA), 1, fPtr);
}
```

А вот вторая вложенная:

```
void ENTER_DATA()
{
    struct DATA notebook;
    printf("Введите фамилию -> ");
    scanf("%s", notebook.surname);
    printf("Введите имя -> ");
    scanf("%s", notebook.name);
    printf("Введите отчество -> ");
    scanf("%s", notebook.patronymic);
    printf("Введите дату рождения:\nДень -> ");
    scanf("%u", &notebook.BirthDate);
    printf("Месяц -> ");
    scanf("%u", &notebook.BirthMonth);
    printf("Год -> ");
    scanf("%u", &notebook.BirthYear);
    printf("Введите адрес:\nУлица -> ");
    scanf("%s", notebook.addresSTREET);
    printf("Номер дома -> ");
    scanf("%u", &notebook.addresHOME);
    printf("Введите номер мобильного телефона -> ");
    scanf("%u", &notebook.mobileNUMBER);
}
```

Comment: Передавайте во вторую функцию адрес структуры. Вот так -- `void UPDATE_RECORD(FILE* fPtr)
{
    struct DATA notebook; ... ENTER_DATA(&notebook); ... } void ENTER_DATA(struct DATA *notebook)
{ ... scanf("%s", notebook->surname); ...}`

Comment: @avp спасибо, заработало)